# How to get JSON object from array of JSON objects in postman?

Tags: json, postman, postman-testcase

Looked for while on other threads and questions didn't get how to get JSON object in array 
questions I have already looked at - 
[How to get JSONobject from JSONArray in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745918/how-to-get-jsonobject-from-jsonarray-in-postman)
[How to get array from JSON Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185839/how-to-get-array-from-json-object)

what I have tried so far -

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var jsonObject = jsonData.events[2];
console.log("jsonobject - " + jsonObject);
```

console output -

```
jsonobject - [object Object]
```

json response looks like this -

```
[
 {

        "$ts": "2019-06-14T06:21:55.2221392Z",
        "values": [
            "43912",
            "CountIn",
            "neet.row.mac3.indexinput",
            "mac3",
            "mac3",
            "mac3",
            300,
            11,
            1,
            "mac3",
            "2019-06-14T06:21:55.2221392Z",
            "2019-06-14T06:22:55.2221392Z",
            "manager",
            "lead",
            "consultant",
            "5ca1e66d7eb20a11f00e502c
        ]
    },
    {

        "$ts": "2019-06-14T06:23:54.3263475Z",
        "values": [
            "44272",
            "indexinput",
            "neet.row.mac2.indexinput",
            "mac2",
            "mac2",
            "mac2",
            300,
            11,
            1,
            "mac2",
            "2019-06-14",
            "2019-06-14",
            "Head",
            "Master",
            "Student",
            "5ca1e66d7eb20a11f00e502c"
        ]
    },
    {
        "$ts": "2019-06-14T06:24:54.3753534Z",
        "values": [
            "44452",
            "indexinput",
            "neet.row.mac.indexinput",
            "mac",
            "mac",
            "mac",
            300,
            11,
            1,
            "Neet",
            "2019-06-14T06:24:54.3753534Z",
            "something1",
            "something2 of something1",
            "something3 of something2 ",
            "5ca1e66d7eb20a11f00e502c"

        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because `jsonObject` is object of objects so when you say console.log(jsonObject) it will show you object values in postman's console. but 
postman console does not shows values of objects in console when it is appended to string message. To see values inside object `stringify` it something like this -

```
console.log("jsonobject - " + JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

it will print values in console for your object

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting the object, but the console is printing it as [object Object].  Try printing `jsonObject.$ts` or `jsonObject.values[0]` to see if the object contains the data you are looking for.